# Github actions build jar with maven and use for docker image building

Tags: maven, docker, github, yaml, github-actions

i want that a git push should trigger `mvn clean package` and build a docker image with the build jar.
Sadly I get following error at the image building

```
Step 2/4 : ADD target/de-sy-file.jar de-sy-file.jar
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder601875986/target/de-sy-file.jar: no such file or directory
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Can anybody tell me where I find the builded jar?

Action.yml

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

name: Push to Amazon ECR

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run:
        mvn clean package --file pom.xml

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: eu-central-1

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: de-sy-file
        IMAGE_TAG:  latest
      run: |
        # Build a docker container and
        # push it to ECR so that it can
        # be deployed to ECS.
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to download and upload an artifact.

My new action.yml :

```
# This workflow will build and push a new container image to Amazon ECR,
# and then will deploy a new task definition to Amazon ECS, on every push
# to the master branch.
#
# To use this workflow, you will need to complete the following set-up steps:
#
# 1. Create an ECR repository to store your images.
#    For example: `aws ecr create-repository --repository-name my-ecr-repo --region us-east-2`.
#    Replace the value of `ECR_REPOSITORY` in the workflow below with your repository's name.
#    Replace the value of `aws-region` in the workflow below with your repository's region.
#
# 2. Create an ECS task definition, an ECS cluster, and an ECS service.
#    For example, follow the Getting Started guide on the ECS console:
#      https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-2#/firstRun
#    Replace the values for `service` and `cluster` in the workflow below with your service and cluster names.
#
# 3. Store your ECS task definition as a JSON file in your repository.
#    The format should follow the output of `aws ecs register-task-definition --generate-cli-skeleton`.
#    Replace the value of `task-definition` in the workflow below with your JSON file's name.
#    Replace the value of `container-name` in the workflow below with the name of the container
#    in the `containerDefinitions` section of the task definition.
#
# 4. Store an IAM user access key in GitHub Actions secrets named `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.
#    See the documentation for each action used below for the recommended IAM policies for this IAM user,
#    and best practices on handling the access key credentials.

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

name: Push to Amazon ECR

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run:
        mvn clean package --file pom.xml

    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - run: mkdir -p target/

    - run: echo hello > target/de-sy-file.jar

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
       name: de-sy-file
       path: target/

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1


    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
      with:
          name: de-sy-file
          path: target/

    - run: cat target/de-sy-file.jar
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: eu-central-1

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: de-sy-file
        IMAGE_TAG:  latest
      run: |
        # Build a docker container and
        # push it to ECR so that it can
        # be deployed to ECS.
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

https://github.com/actions/download-artifact

Answer (score 1):

The artifact should already be stored in the temporary workspace, so you shouldn't have to upload/download.

```
#Author: Ben Francom
name: Build

#on: workflow_dispatch
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - "main"

jobs:
    build:
        name: Package & Deploy
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        timeout-minutes: 25
        steps:
            - name: Cancel Previous Runs
              uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.6.0
              with:
                  access_token: ${{ github.token }}

            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - name: Set up JDK 8
              uses: actions/setup-java@v1
              with:
                  java-version: 8

            - name: Cache local Maven repository
              uses: actions/cache@v2
              with:
                  path: ~/.m2
                  key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      ${{ runner.os }}-maven-


            - name: Maven Package
              run: mvn -B package -DskipTests -f ./pom.xml

            -   name: Configure AWS credentials

                uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
                with:
                    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
                    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
                    aws-region: us-east-1

            -   name: Login to Amazon ECR
                id: login-ecr
                uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

            -   name: set env
                id: vars
                run: |
                    echo ::set-output name=github_short_sha::$(echo ${GITHUB_SHA:0:7})

            -   name: Build & Push Image
                id: build-image
                env:
                    DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
                    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
                    ECR_REPOSITORY: app-repo
                    IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.github_short_sha }}
                run: |
                    docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
                    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
                    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
                    echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

            -   name: Fill in the new image ID for App Fargate task definition
                id: app-task-def
                uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
                with:
                    task-definition: .aws/prod-definition.json
                    container-name: prod-app-container
                    image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}


            -   name: Deploy App Fargate Task
                uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
                with:
                    task-definition: ${{ steps.app-task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
                    service: prod-service
                    cluster: prod-cluster
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim as builder
#WORKDIR build
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir target
ARG JAR_FILE=./target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} target/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/target/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain a complex, but probably not ideal, solution to this.

Let's say I have a multi-module Maven project that looks like this

```
│
├── cluster
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
│
├── common
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
│
├── loadbalancer
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
│
└── pom.xml
```

This Maven project generates two JARs application, one `loadbalancer` app and the `cluster` app. What I want to do is create two different images for these two JAR apps.

Before setting up my GitHub Action what I would do is run

```
mvn clean install
docker build -t myimage/loadbalancer:latest ./loadbalancer
docker build -t myimage/cluster_node:latest ./cluster
```

The first command is going to generate my JARs in `loadbalancer/target/` and `cluster/target/` and then I'm going to take those JAR files into the docker image by building these two `Dockerfile`s

```
FROM fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY target/cluster.jar ./cluster.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "cluster.jar"]
```

```
FROM fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY target/loadbalancer.jar ./loadbalancer.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "loadbalancer.jar"]
```

This is all you're going to need on your local computer.

The best part of all this is that you can do exactly this with GitHub Actions (but there could be a better way of dockerizing Maven projects), here's a GitHub Action that:

1. Tests and builds `loadbalancer.jar` and `cluster.jar`
2. Builds two Docker images with those newly generated `.jar`s
3. Tags each image with two different tags:

   a. `latest`

   b. 8-digit of the commit that triggered this action
4. Pushes them to the newly released GitHub Container Registry

```yaml
name: Maven test & Docker build-push

on:
  push:
    branches: [ development ]

jobs:
  build:
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set SHA8
      run: echo ::set-env name=SHA8::$(git log --oneline -1 | awk '{print $1}')

    - name: Test SHA8
      run: echo $SHA8

    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1.4.2
      with:
        java-version: '11.0.8'

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install

    - name: Login to GitHub Registry Container
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: ghcr.io
        username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
        password: ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }}

    - name: Create docker loadbalancer image
      run: docker build -t ghcr.io/myimage/loadbalancer:latest -t ghcr.io/myimage/loadbalancer:$SHA8 ./loadbalancer

    - name: Create docker cluster_node image
      run: docker build -t ghcr.io/myimage/cluster_node:latest -t ghcr.io/myimage/cluster_node:$SHA8 ./cluster

    - name: Push docker images
      run: |
        docker push ghcr.io/myimage/loadbalancer:latest
        docker push ghcr.io/myimage/loadbalancer:$SHA8
        docker push ghcr.io/myimage/cluster_node:latest
        docker push ghcr.io/myimage/cluster_node:$SHA8
```